# https reverse proxy nginx to nodejs

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

i have a problem with Nginx configuration 
i have Nodejs application and i need proxy Nginx to Nodejs on HTTPS,
also i have valid certificate too
i get this message on chrome and similar on firefox.

this is my nginx conf

```
upstream nodejs {

    server 127.0.0.1:8000 max_fails=0;
}
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name mydomain.ir;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my_domain_ir.csr;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my_domain_ir.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=500;
    location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What is the message?

Comment: hi,on Chrome message is :"This site can’t provide a secure connection", error:ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
on Firefox message is : "Secure Connection Failed", Error code: SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT

Comment: Are you sure that `my_domain_ir.csr` contains your certificate? Usually, `.csr` is used for the *Certificate Signing Request* file.

Comment: hi, yes i'm sure about that

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from DNS server, i used cloudflare Free plan for DNS server, Then i did setup and configure bind9 on my vps and my problem solved;